# Can't recreate dropped tables to any MySQL database using Python and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, pycharm

Our class has an assignment to create 3 tables in a database using PyCharm for programming the .py code and PHPMyAdmin to view said tables.

I was able to create the three tables on my database through Python programming on the first try. However, our programming professor required us to screen record our output, so I dropped my tables and tried to re-run my .py file and recreate them so that I can show in the screen recording that my .py code does work, but they won't create. I tried:

1. Changing the name of the database
2. Changing the name of tables
3. Creating the tables on test database, but the tables are not getting created.

My code has a try and except that displays an SQL error if it happens to cross by one, however in all cases above, the SQL queries have shown to be successful. When I check the tables in PHPMyAdmin to verify, however, the database returns 0 tables.

This is my conn file

```
import mysql.connector  # allows to connect to db
from mysql.connector import Error  # easily get error

try:
    conx = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database="_dbmidtermlab_maceren", user='root', password='')
    if conx.is_connected():
        db_info = conx.get_server_info()  # get info about sql server
        print("Connected to MYSQL Server Version: ", db_info)
        cursor = conx.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        db = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", db)
except Error as e:
    print("Error connecting to MYSQL", e)
```

My Create Tables file

```
from conn import conx
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
    createTable = """CREATE TABLE Order (OrderNum varchar(5) NOT NULL ,OrderDate date NULL,CustomerNum VARCHAR(3) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (OrderNum)); 
                     CREATE TABLE Parts (PartNum varchar(4) NOT NULL ,Description varchar(15) NULL,onHand decimal(4,0) NULL, Class varchar(2) NULL,Warehouse varchar(1) NULL, Price decimal(6,2) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (PartNum)); 
                     CREATE TABLE Customers (CustomerNum varchar(3) NOT NULL ,CustomerName varchar(35) NOT NULL,Street varchar(15) NULL, City varchar(15) NULL,State varchar(2) NULL, Zip varchar(5) NULL,  Balance decimal(8,2) NULL,  CreditLimit decimal(8,2) NULL,  RepNum varchar(2) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNum)); """
    cursor = conx.cursor() #cursor allows to execute query (simiplay to mysqli_query())
    result = cursor.execute(createTable, multi=True)
    conx.commit()
    #multi=True allows multiple queries in one variable

    print("Tables created successfully")
except Error as error:
    print("Failed to create table in MySQL: {}".format(error))
#finally:
 #   if conx.is_connected():
  #      cursor.close()
   ##    print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Based on what I've Googled, apparently dropping the tables was a bad idea. It somehow affected the functionality? What should I do?

Comment: Why won't they create? Are you getting errors? What are the errors? Show your code.

Comment: Dropping the tables shouldn't be a problem if you have the code to recreate them.

Comment: @Barmar added the code. My code has a try and except that displays an SQL error if it happens to cross by one, however in all cases I tried above, the SQL queries have shown to be successful. When I check the tables in PHPMyAdmin to verify, however, the database returns 0 tables.

Comment: What happens if you run the "create table" statements in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Try doing them as separate queries instead of using `multi=True`

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar! Separating the queries worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much to @Barmar and @IODEV!

What solved my problem:

1. Separating my CREATE TABLE queries as suggested by @Barmar
2. Adding `` to the ORDER table as suggested by @IODEV

Still wondering why my multi-query worked the first time and bugged out afterwards, but for now, my project is finally working! Thank you!

Comment: Did you really need to do both?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that MySQL requires backticks for identifiers if the name used is a reserved keyword. In this case table name Order is a reserved keyword (ie sql order by...) thus you have to use backticks around `Order` ie:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (OrderNum varchar(5) NOT NULL, OrderDate date NULL, CustomerNum VARCHAR(3) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (OrderNum));
```

In order to make it easier to trace similar problems in the future I would suggest you execute the SQL DDL-statements separately ie one `cursor.execute` for each `create table ...`